# Kubernetes Networkpolicy dosen't block traffic

Tags: kubernetes, calico, kubernetes-networkpolicy

i've a namespace called: `test`, and containing 3 pods: `frontend`, `backend` and `database`.

this is the manifest of pods:

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: frontend
  namespace: test
  labels:
    app: todo
    tier: frontend
spec:
  containers:
    - name: frontend
      image: nginx

---

kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: backend
  namespace: test
  labels:
    app: todo
    tier: backend
spec:
  containers:
    - name: backend
      image: nginx

---

kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: database
  namespace: test
  labels:
    app: todo
    tier: database
spec:
  containers:
    - name: database
      image: mysql
      env:
      - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
        value: example
```

I would implement a network policy , that allow only allow incoming traffic from the backend to the database but disallow incoming traffic from the frontend.

this my network policy:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: app-allow
  namespace: test
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: todo
      tier: database
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
  ingress:
  - from:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: todo
          tier: backend
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3306
    - protocol: UDP
      port: 3306
```

This is the output of `kubectl get pods -n test -o wide`

```
NAME       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP           NODE       NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
backend    1/1     Running   0          28m   172.17.0.5   minikube   <none>           <none>
database   1/1     Running   0          28m   172.17.0.4   minikube   <none>           <none>
frontend   1/1     Running   0          28m   172.17.0.3   minikube   <none>           <none>
```

This is the output of `kubectl get networkpolicy -n test -o wide`

```
NAME        POD-SELECTOR             AGE
app-allow   app=todo,tier=database   21m
```

when i execute `telnet @ip-of-mysql-pod 3306` from the `frontend` pod , the connection look be established and the network policy is not working

```
kubectl exec -it pod/frontend bash -n test
kubectl exec [POD] [COMMAND] is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version. Use kubectl exec [POD] -- [COMMAND] instead.
root@frontend:/# telnet 172.17.0.4 3306
Trying 172.17.0.4...
Connected to 172.17.0.4.
Escape character is '^]'.
J
8.0.25 k{%J\�#(t%~qI%7caching_sha2_password
```

there are something i missing ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you installed a CNI that implement the Network Policies? E.g. Cilium?

Comment: @Jonas yes ; i ve calico as CNI

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you forgot to add "default deny" policy:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny-ingress
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
```

The default behavior of `NetworkPolicy` is to allow all connections between pod unless explicitly denied.

More details here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#default-deny-all-ingress-traffic

Comment: I am facing same issue. I am implementing network plicies with namespace and inter-namespace but it is not working as expected. I am using telnet for testing. I have rabbitmq cluster in rabbitmq-0 namespace and apply default deny but nothing happen.